# NFS Server hangs on proxmox

Tags: nfs, proxmox

I have a proxmox host running BTRFS. I installed debian 8.4 on my server with BTRFS as root filesystem, and then installed proxmox on top of that. This setup runs fine.

Now I'm trying to use this host to export some NFS shares. The shares are visible to remote hosts, but interacting with the NFS shares causes timeouts on the client. I tested this on both Mac OSX and arch linux clients.

Exports:

```
/var/shares 10.20.0.64(rw,subtree_check,fsid=0)
/var/shares/media 10.20.0.0/24(rw,subtree_check)
```

Log on arch linux client:

```
Sep 13 21:53:15 [CLIENT_HOSTNAME] kernel: nfs: server [SERVER_HOSTNAME] not responding, timed out
Sep 13 21:55:01 [CLIENT_HOSTNAME] kernel: nfs: server [SERVER_HOSTNAME] not responding, still trying
Sep 13 21:55:30 [CLIENT_HOSTNAME] kernel: nfs: server [SERVER_HOSTNAME] OK
Sep 13 21:57:48 [CLIENT_HOSTNAME] kernel: nfs: server [SERVER_HOSTNAME] not responding, timed out
Sep 13 21:59:31 [CLIENT_HOSTNAME] kernel: nfs: server [SERVER_HOSTNAME] not responding, still trying
Sep 13 22:00:00 [CLIENT_HOSTNAME] kernel: nfs: server [SERVER_HOSTNAME] OK
```

Comment: Is the NFS server actually accessible during those times? Why have you used btrfs?

Comment: Seriously try not performing subtree checks, particularly with btrfs. The security benefits of doing that are dubious at best. So no_subtree_check.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I used btrfs for migitating bit-rot and it's capability add and remove disks while remaining online. What do you mean with whether the server is accessible? I'm on the same network, no VPN connections whatshowever. While this happens my SSH shell works fine.

Comment: I just tested no_subtree_check - it didn't resolve the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Outline the problem, accept your answer and get upvotes from people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the problem turned out to reside in my network configuration. NFS now works properly.

Comment: A bit more information about what the problem was in the configuration and how it manifested itself would be appreciated. That way the next person with a similar problem may find your answer helpful.